# Phonegap - Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'd like to explain what does "Javascript not working" mean, but the only thing I can do is tell that the code is never executing, and don't know how to debug.

Let's start: I'm developing a Phonegap application - in that sense, I don't have a console object to check on.

This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>1001Carros</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
        adaptandose a dispositivo ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        switch(device.platform) {
            case "iPhone":
                location.href = "index-iphone.html"; break;
            case "Android":
            case "BlackBerry":
            case "BlackBerry WebWorks":
                location.href = "index-android.html"; break;
            default:
                location.href = "index-android.html";
        }
    }
};
```

My intention is: when the document is loaded, initialize() is called. Such method would verify the platform and redirect to the appropiate screen.

[When I run my app in the emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) (which finally appends `?enableripple=cordova` to my url), I get that "phonegap.js" does not exist. If that's the problem, it seems easy to explain why I'm not being redirected.

However, when I compile the application via local tools (i.e. `phonegap run android`) such file seems to be created in the `assets` directory (in android platform).

**Question**: How can I debug this issue? I'm using the emulator and, alternatively, a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. I would like to debug the device and see if the problem is with the file (as it is shown in the emulator/ripple) or is it elsewhere.

It'd be great if someone with more experience could help me if they had a similar problem since it's my first phonegap application.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about debugging, since your devices most likely don't have a console, you'll have to use alerts. I like to use alerts to test if a function is firing, if the appropriate data is being stored/passed, etc.

As for why your javascript is not working, I'm not positive but I think it has to do with you using "app". I believe that is reserved for native phonegap things, as seen in "navigator.app.exit()". I would suggest you rename the variable and try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly. But i see your code has issue. In phonegap, all API device(provided by phonegap) must be call when event deviceready fired:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
  // Code here
}, false);
```

In phonegap, support many tools to debug app now: [phonegap debug](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap), [weinre is power](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html)
You can use console.log('...'), it support any device, see log in your IDE: Xcode, Eclipse,..

Comment: Please read document clearly when config and use any tools. I have been working many tools debug, it working well.

Comment: Please point me any doc. There are a lot of videos and neither of what I found actually helped me :s.

Comment: BTW I found the error. But still have no luck regarding the Device plugin (I thought it was a built in feature but seemed to stop being so in version 3 or something alike - i'm nw at this)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to debug your phonegap code on android:

- logcat
- Weinre: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html
- Chrome Remote Debugging (only Android 4.4+): https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
- ..

Comment: I included this file using weinre: `<script src="http://192.168.10.133:8080/target/target-script-min.js"></script>`. I set the access directive to * in my config. I get the error: "the connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Comment: This error usually happens when it cannot reach the url..
Is your phone connected to the same local network ? try to past this url to the device browser to see if it works.

Comment: finally I made it connect. however console.log messages are never shown, and if i execute something in the remote console, the change is not reflected (the tutorial suggests that)